# How to set different colored/width borders on a layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to set different colored and width borders to top/bottom/start/end of a layout in android, i've tried the following but it didnt work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
        android:start="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#FF7539"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
        android:top="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
        android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
        android:end="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item
        android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:start="5dp" android:end="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it might be help you : https://www.android-examples.com/create-set-multiple-color-border-around-textview-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone else wants to do this, I first made a layout background with all black strokes that i needed on 3 of my sides

**bg_border_transactions.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/textBlack" android:width="1dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and for my specfic left color I did this drawable and set as background where necessary

**border_food.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_border_transactions">
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="start" android:width="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/foodColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```